# How to check ajax's response from laravel's controller is empty?

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I work on laravel project with ajax. Below is my controller.

```php
public function Student(Request $request){
    $student = Student::where('school_uuid',$request->school_uuid)
        ->where('cardid',$request->cardid)
        ->first();
    return response()->json($student);
}
```

And this is my ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('api.student') }}",
    method:"POST",
    data:{
        cardid:cardid,
        school_uuid:"{{$shareuser->school_uuid}}",
    },
    success:function(response){
        if (typeof response.name !== 'undefined'){
            console.log(response.name);
        }else{
            console.log("no data");
        }
    }
});
```

I can check the empty response by using `typeof response.name !== 'undefined'` and it work fine. But I'm not sure that is the best way or not. Any advice or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send the correct response code if the `student` isn't found, and then handle that in the javascript.

For example:

```php
public function Student(Request $request){
    $student = Student::where('school_uuid',$request->school_uuid)
        ->where('cardid',$request->cardid)
        ->firstOrFail(); // This will cause a 404 if the student does not exist
    return response()->json($student);
}
```

And then in your JS:

```js
$.ajax({
    url:"{{ route('api.student') }}",
    method:"POST",
    data:{
        cardid:cardid,
        school_uuid:"{{$shareuser->school_uuid}}",
    },
    success:function(response){
        console.log(response.name);
    },
    error: function(xhr) {
        if (xhr.status === 404) {
            // Handle 404 error
        }

        // Handle any other error
    }
});
```

Comment: Dear atymic, Thank you very much.